# How to make a navigation service with Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro 3 in my MVVM WPF Application. I succesfully managed to implement navigation in my app by following the [documentation](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/) and the samples provided.

However, **I want to follow the [SOLID principles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(informatique))** and I think that using a ShellViewModel as a Conductor is a violation of the single responsibility principle.

In order to resolve this problem I created a "service" which control my navigation but **I can't manage to display the ActiveItem**. When I navigate, I have the ViewModel name as a string instead of the View associated with it.

```
public class NavigationService : Conductor<IScreen>, INavigationService
{
    public void GoTo<T>() where T : IScreen
    {
        var viewModel = IoC.Get<T>();
        ActivateItem(viewModel);
    }
}
```

And I use it from my "ShellViewModel".

```
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public HomeViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public INavigationService NavigationService => _navigationService;

    public void ShowChartPage() => _navigationService.GoTo<TimeSeriesViewModel>();

}
```

The ContentControl from my ShellView :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding NavigationService.ActiveItem}" />
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem which causes you issue regards your XAML snippet: you are binding the `Content` property directly to your *ViewModel* (`TimeSeriesViewModel`), then your application cannot work as you wish. In this situation you will see just a string which represents the type of the object that you are binding to the `ContentControl`.

To make you application work correctly you have to use:

1. **Caliburn's naming convention** i.e. you name your `ContentControl` in a proper way, so Caliburn can create automatically a binding for you.
2. **a Caliburn attached property** called `View.Model`.

Both these approaches retrieve the right View for the ViewModel that your infer in the ActiveItem property of your `Conductor`.

In the first case your can use `<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />` (but you need to create the corresponding property in the `ShellViewModel` class); with the second approach you can use `<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding NavigationService.ActiveItem}" /`>.

I hope that my hint and my quick explanation can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I needed to use cal:View.Model attached property.